# How can I link to a local image for a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I want to display an image on a page within my Google Chrome extension, but I want to store the image within a folder called "images" within my chrome extension. How do I link to this image? What URL do I use?

I need it to go here (in place of "URL"). How do I implement it?

```
<a href="URL"><img src="URL" /></a>
```

### UPDATE

answer did not work; still need help.

Answer (score 6):

`var url = chrome.extension.getURL('/folder/file.png');`

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL

---

Update: Added working example.

In `index.html`:

```
<img id='someid' src="">

<script>
  var img = document.getElementById('someid');
  img.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/images/google.png');
</script>
```

In `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1"
}
```

Opening `chrome-extension://xyz/index.html` shows the image as expected.

Comment: OK but how about if I need it to be dynamic? Can I have a full url link to the file?

Comment: I need it to go in place of "URL". How do I implement it? `<a href="URL"><img src="URL" /></a>`

Comment: now I also see you put "URL" in the `href` part instead of the actual URL. What do I put in place of `URL`?

Comment: Oh. You can just leave the href empty. For an `img` it is the same. Just change `href` to `src`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9447/discussion-between-webaddict-and-abraham)

Comment: ok i left `href` and `src` blank but it does not display the image or link. it's just blank on the page.

Comment: isn't there anything nowadays that solves the problem straight away on the `src` attribute of `img`, rather than having to solve programmaticaly things that you should be able to directly solve via `html`? (such a simple path)

Answer (score 0):

For `manifest_version >= 3` you must use `chrome.runtime.getURL('/images/google.png')`

Btw you must add into your `web_accessible_resources` this files.

Example:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "images/google.png"
            ],
            "extension_ids": [
                "*"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://*.somesite.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
```